# Newly created branch is not up-to-date with remote counterpart?

Tags: git

I am trying to update a fork of my project with the latest updates from the original project's `master`. (I'm not the maintainer of the fork, but the maintainer of the fork isn't familiar with Git and relies on me to do this for him.)

Previously, I have not had any trouble doing this, but now I'm finding that for some reason Git is telling me that pushing to his branch would be non-fast-forward, even though I'm creating my local branch based on the latest version of the remote `master`.

Using `FORK` as the remote fork name, and without actually performing the merge of the latest updates from the original project, here's what's happening:

```
> git fetch FORK
> git checkout -b fork_master FORK/master
Branch fork_master set up to track remote branch master from FORK.
Switched to a new branch 'fork_master'
> git push FORK master
To git@<fork-URL>.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@<fork-URL>.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

As you can see, I `fetch` right before creating the branch, create the branch from `FORK master`, and then immediately push back to `FORK master` *without making any changes*.

Calling `git fetch` again produces no output (again), so the fork is not being updated in between my original `fetch` and my `push`.

I have tried deleting and re-establishing my `remote` corresponding to the `FORK`, but that has not changed the behavior.

What could possibly be going on here? I'm using `git 2.1.4`.

**EDIT:** As a workaround, I've created an entirely new clone with `FORK` as origin and the original as a separate remote. I encountered no problems with the merge-and-push when doing it this way. I'd still like to know why my original attempt failed, though.

Comment: You are creating a local branch called `fork_master` but in your push command you are pushing your local `master` branch.

Comment: @1615903 I thought that in the `push <remote> <branch>` syntax, `<branch>` was the name of the *remote* branch to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the numbered user noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999145/newly-created-branch-is-not-up-to-date-with-remote-counterpart#comment57726470_34999145O), you are requesting that git push the tip of your local `master` branch to the remote's `master` branch.

The reason is that in the syntax for `git push remote refspec`, the final argument is a "refspec", not just a branch name.  Loosely speaking, a refspec is a *pair* of branch names, such as `fork_master:master`.  For `push`, the left hand side name is your local branch tip, and the right hand side name is the name you ask the remote to update.

Writing a single branch name like `master` means, for `git push`, `master:master`.

(Everything is a bit different with `fetch`, where the left side matches the remote's names and the right side is your names, and omitting the right side of a refspec means "don't update anything, just drop the result into `FETCH_HEAD`".)